# how to run tests in specific order in tfs2015

Tags: tfs-2015

In tfs2013 we use vsmdi and tests setting to run tests in specific order.
Now, in tfs2015 we don't want to use tesstetting. 
How to run tests in specific order in tfs2015?

Answer (score 2):

To run tests in order in Vnext build , you could add an **Ordered Test file** in your test project and run it in Vnext Build.

1. Add an Order Test file in your test project and use it to define the
   testing order.
2. In your build template, add  an Visual Studio Test. Change the Test Assembly like the picture below.
   [image]

Please refer more info: [How to: Create an Ordered Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In my Opinion its possible. In the Test Drop location i have the complete Project, and in the Executions folder i have the ordered test. please contact me in case of questions, hope it helps  [image]